# Enviar vários e-mails em lista vinda do MySQL com PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar alguns e-mails com o PHPMailer mas sempre recebe uma mensagem de erro:

> Invalid address: meu@gmail.com,outro.cruz@web.com.br

Já verifiquei tudo o que conheço mas ainda não consegui, aqui minha lista está sendo montada e a tentativa de envio:

```
// BUSCANDO PRODUTOS
$RelEmail = "SELECT cadUsuario.Email,
                    cadPessoa.Nome AS NomeTransp
            FROM cadUsuario
            INNER JOIN cadPessoa ON (cadUsuario.IdPessoa = cadPessoa.IdPessoa)
            WHERE (cadPessoa.Papel = 'Transportadora')
            AND (cadPessoa.Ativo = 1)";
$stm = $conn->prepare($RelEmail);
// $stm->bindValue(1, $IdPessoa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();    
$RelEmail = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
// CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
$ContReg = count($RelEmail); 
// FECHANDO A CONSULTA
$stm->closeCursor(); 

foreach($RelEmail as $RegTransportadoras) {
    if ($ListaEmails == "") {
        $ListaEmails = $RegTransportadoras->Email;
    } else {
        $ListaEmails = $ListaEmails.",".$RegTransportadoras->Email;
    }
}

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta class
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->IsSMTP(); 

try {
     $mail->Host = 'smtp.seudominio.com.br'; 
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
     $mail->Port       = 587; 
     $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
     $mail->Username = 'suporte@web.com.br'; 
     $mail->Password = 'secreta'; 
     $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
     $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
     $mail->SetLanguage("br");

     $mail->SetFrom('valter.martins@web.com.br', 'Nome'); 
     $mail->AddReplyTo('valter.martins@web.com.br', 'Nome'); 
     $mail->Subject = 'Assunto';
     $mail->AddAddress($ListaEmails, 'Teste');
     $mail->AddCC($ListaEmails, 'Destinatario'); // Copia
     //$mail->AddBCC('destinatario_oculto@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario2`'); // Cópia Oculta
     //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // Adicionar um anexo

     $mail->MsgHTML('corpo do email'); 
     $mail->Send();
     echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso\n";


    }catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
}
```

Comment: Não deves dar as credenciais de hosting, username e pw quando metes online tem cuidado com isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre no método `AddAdress`, você precisa setar um email por vez, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
$mail->AddAddress('recipient1@domain.com', 'First Name');
$mail->AddAddress('recipient2@domain.com', 'Second Name');
$mail->AddAddress('recipient3@domain.com', 'Third Name');
```

No seu caso o ideal é percorrer o array `$RelEmail` em um foreach fazendo a chamada desse método para cada elemento do array.